# CKEDITOR Problem on MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I don't know how to use CKEditor in Mvc2 Framework.

I tried but it will not work

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ABSTRACT) %>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("$ABSTRACT").ckeditor();
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `$` with `#` and it should definitely works

```
$("#ABSTRACT").ckeditor();
```

also be sure to have this 2 scripts referenced in your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Content.Url("~/yourpath/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Content.Url("~/yourpath/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js")"></script>
```

You can also consider to associate ckEditor to a class instead of the Id of controls. so with only one call you can set the editor for all the control that have that class in your apps.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any way you could just use the asp.net usercontrol for ckeditor?

http://ckeditor.com/download  3rd one down.

I have not tried it in mvc but I do not see why it would not work in MVC.